# Selector's "jump" in NavigationItem calling function that is in parent NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, selector, uinavigationitem

I have the following setup in code:

```
class MyNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        let myNavItem = MyNavigationItem()
        setItems([myNavItem], animated: false)
    }

    //Weird, the selector of the item calls this function
    func doSomething() {
        //   This do some stuff
    } 
}

class MyNavigationItem: UINavigationItem {

    private let myButton :UIBarButtonItem  = {
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "ic_topnav_userpic"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: nil, action: #selector(doSomething))
        return barButton
    }()

    // Initializers

    init() {
        super.init(title: "Title")
        rightBarButtonItem = myButton
    }
    //..other initializers        

    //This function is never called
    func doSomething() {
      //   This should do some stuff
    } 
}
```

When I make any `UINavigationBar` in my `Storyboard` of type `MyNavigationBar`. Then, the function that is "selected" when I tap over `myButton` item is the one present in `MyNavigationBar`'s implementation.

Why is this happening?

It should behave this way?, I was expecting that the function called were the one inside `MyNavigationItem`.

Answer (score 2):

So, here's the thing:

When I stated:

```
private let myButton :UIBarButtonItem  = {
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "ic_topnav_userpic"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: nil, action: #selector(doSomething))
        return barButton
    }()
```

This method is executed **before** having an instance of this class (a.k.a `self`) so this was preventing me from doing `#selector(self.doSomething)` as **@Dershowitz123** suggested.

A quick way to avoid this is making this **`let`** variable a **lazy var** instead:

```
private lazy var myButton :UIBarButtonItem  = {
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "ic_topnav_userpic"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: #selector(self.showEditProfile))
        return barButton
    }()
```

> The only thing that still is *weird* to me is this **jump** that
>   `Selector`s do when in such situation.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

```
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "ic_topnav_userpic"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: nil, action: #selector(doSomething))
```

**Target** should be `self` and `#selector(self.doSomething)`.

Comment: You're just writing the function but never really calling it. You call a function either with objects or you write it in another function which you know will execute for sure. But the function you're writing in `class MyNavigationItem: UINavigationItem` is just any other function. It isn't getting called anywhere, unlike the one you wrote in `class MyNavigationBar: UINavigationBar` 's `override func awakeFromNib()` which **FOR SURE** is called.

Comment: but why? my selector is pointing to the one in MyNavigationItem. I can even delete the one in MyNavigationBar and it will not complain. Just that nothing is going to happen when tapping the button

Comment: You haven't told it to which `doSomething()` method you're referring to. Try `#selector(self.doSomething)`. It should work. And `target should be set to self and not nil`.

Comment: You are close, there's something else going on here, I will add an answer detailing it in a few minutes